# How to reward agent's action in self-play adversarial game reinforcement learning?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I am beginner in this field and I am trying to implement an agent playing an adversarial game like chess. I create two agents that share the same neural network and experience buffer. In every step, the neural network will be updated by both agents (features order swapped).

Does my self-play approach make sense? And if it does, how will I reward the agent's behaviors?

More clearly, following this:

(0) state -> (1) agent0 action -> (2) reward -> (3) state -> (4) agent1 action -> (5) reward -> (6) state

Is the next state of agent0 after (1) would be (3) or (6)? And is the corresponding reward (2) or (5) or something else (for example (2) - (5))?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding. You start with two randomized initialized networks. Please don't share the network. Then you train one of them and only that one. When the network under training begins to show some progress, you stop this match and you make a copy of the good network to be the new opponent. Then you continue. This way you bootstrap yourself and the opponents. You don't try to learn against an expert, but rather against someone who is more or less equal to you.
Above I've described saving only one copy of a previous you, but you can of course keep the last 10 instances and play against all of those.

Comment: Maybe what I've described above is my interpretation and is different from what was already proven to work. Maybe you are right and you do play the agent against itself and you can/should use the same network. Just one observation, you need to keep a few old copies and evaluate against those just to make sure you are indeed getting better rather than learning to play well against yourself (overfit).